# PHPExcel convert XLS to CSV with special characters

Tags: php, mysql, csv, converters, phpexcel

I'm having a small issue while converting an XLS file containing special characters to CSV file using PHPExcel classes.

As exemple the name "Kévin" gives "KÃ©vin" in the CSV generated file.

Here is my current PHP code using PHPExcel :

```
$excel_readers = array(
        'Excel5' , 
        'Excel2003XML' , 
        'Excel2007'
        );

        require_once('classes/PHPExcel.php');

        $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
        $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

        $path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $excel = $reader->load($path);

        $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
        $writer->save('temp/absences.csv');

        echo 'File saved to csv format';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

/**
    Convert excel file to csv
*/

//Various excel formats supported by PHPExcel library
$excel_readers = array(
    'Excel5' , 
    'Excel2003XML' , 
    'Excel2007'
);

require_once('PHPExcel180/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once('PHPExcel180/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/CSV.php');

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(false);

$path = 'file.xls';
$excel = $reader->load($path);

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
$writer->setUseBOM(true);
$writer->save('data.csv');

echo 'File saved to csv format';
?>
```

PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc 
Library use code

Removes special characters when converting from one xls to csv, code end

Answer (score 3):

The spreadsheet content will be saved in the CSV file encoded as UTF-8

Optionally, you can tell the CSV Writer to write a BOM as well

```
$writer->setUseBOM(true);
```

But it's up to the applications reading that file to treat it correctly as UTF-8 data. Applications like MS Excel itself should handle it properly, but text editors like notepad won't recognise the UTF-8 data.